# How can I increase every json values by 1?

Tags: python, json

My code

```
with open('res1536.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

for group in json_data['resources']:
    group['slot'] = 0
    group['slot'] += 1


with open("RES_Edited.JSON", 'w') as json_edited:
             json.dump(json_data, json_edited, indent = 1)
```

But it save all the slots like "slot": 1
I want it will be "slot": 1
"slot": 2
"slot": 3
...

Thanks!

Comment: use a counter and add it with 1

Answer (score 0):

A good way to count whilst looping is `enumerate`. Docs: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html

```
with open('res1536.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

for i, group in enumerate(json_data['resources']):
    group['slots'] = i


with open("RES_Edited.JSON", 'w') as json_edited:
             json.dump(json_data, json_edited, indent = 1)
```

You could do the same explicitly like:

```
i = 0
for group in json_data['resources']:
    group['slots'] = i
    i += 1
```

Comment: `i++` is not python

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ah yes! Thanks